# Automate Outlook mail scheduler

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I came across a code in Excel VBA which sends mail via Outlook based on given time ranges in the code. The "TO, CC, Subject and Mail Body" are all input in excel only.

The code works fine but `.Send` giving error `287-Application or object defined error`. The code works well in my colleague's laptop, so I am guessing it is some setting error in my outlook or excel. I keep my outlook open while executing the code. The code is written below. Can anyone point to what might be wrong?

```
Sub Send_Email()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    '''''''''' Update Next ''''''''''''''

    Call Update_Next_Schedule_Time
    Application.OnTime sh.Range("K20").Value, "Send_Email"

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim oa As Object
    Dim msg As Object

    Set oa = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    Set msg = oa.createitem(0)

    With msg
        .To = sh.Range("C2").Value
        .CC = sh.Range("C4").Value
        .Subject = sh.Range("C6").Value
        .Body = sh.Range("C8").Value
        .display
        .send
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you type `Doevents` between `.display` and `.send`?

Comment: The outlook opens with the drafted mail but is not auto -sent.

Comment: Did you do what I mentioned above? If yes, did you get any errors?

Comment: I did Doevents and it prepared my mail i.e. it is drafted in outlook. But not sent which means I need to click the send button. However, the code already says ".send" which is unfortunately throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to your Outlook security policy. Check if it allows programmatic access. If not, and you cannot convince your IT department to make any change, then you should automate the opened outlook app rather that creating a new Outlook instance. Also, are you trying to send the email to yourself, by any chance?

Comment: The trust center seems inactive and Anti-virus status is valid. I tried sending to myself as well as others. I think it is security policy which is the issue. How to automate outlook app? Can I try to run this program for my Gmail instead? What changes do you think I need? I would love to see this code running.